# anchor and onclick with asp.net postback

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a link like this

```
<a href="#thumb" id="ctl00_allContent_btnThumb" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$allContent$btnThumb','')"><img alt="" src="../../images/bullet-thumb.gif"></a>
```

On Firefox it does what it supposed to. But it won't work on IE or Chrome.

I know there are some questions on the subject here, but they haven't helped me. I'm guessing it's more specific since it envolves ASP.NET postback.

thank you

Comment: What is it supposed to do and what happens instead?

Comment: Did you create your link using the `<asp:LinkButton>` control? If yes: it should work in any browser. Do you have any other scripts on the page which might break script execution? Are you able to post a link?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have client validation controls on the page.

That controls are not working in Firefox, but working in IE and Chrome.

So probably failing of client validation is blocking you from submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "javascript:" from the event.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to change it to something like this

`<asp:LinkButton ID="myLinkButton"  runat="server" OnClick="myLinkButton_Click"><img alt="" src="../../images/bullet-thumb.gif" style="border:0"></asp:LinkButton>`